# Delayed assignment to a WithEvents backing field

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, inotifypropertychanged

I've noticed that when a property's backing field has the `WithEvents` modifier, value assignment can "lag" for lack of better words. I've reproduced the behavior in a simple demo, so the purpose of `WithEvents` won't be evident here (and thus it won't be constructive to say "just get rid of it")

```
Public Class ItemViewModel
    Public Property Id As Integer
End Class

Public Class ViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase

    Private WithEvents _item As ItemViewModel = New ItemViewModel() With {.Id = 0}
    Public Property Item As ItemViewModel
        Get
            Return _item
        End Get
        Set(value As ItemViewModel)
            SetProperty(_item, value)
        End Set
    End Property
...
```

`SetProperty` definition:

```
Protected Function SetProperty(Of T)(ByRef field As T, value As T, <CallerMemberName> Optional name As String = Nothing) As Boolean
    If (EqualityComparer(Of T).Default.Equals(field, value)) Then
        Return False
    End If
    field = value
    NotifyPropertyChanged(name)
    Return True
End Function
```

When I update the `Item` property to be a new item with an incremented id, the property getter is hit as soon as the event fires, as expected. However, the value of the backing field is still the old value! If I add another `PropertyChanged` event right after the `SetProperty` call, the backing field will have the correct value at that point. Of course, if I take out `WithEvents`, it works as expected with only one event.

This is the only time I've seen `SetProperty` fail in such a way. What is the problem that `WithEvents` is causing?

UPDATE: When `ViewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` directly, instead of inheriting from the base, and raises `PropertyChanged` after setting the value, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's going on here is that `WithEvents` is a feature that the .NET Framework itself does not natively support. VB.NET is implementing it on top of .NET. The feature is there because it was also provided by VB6. The way the feature was implemented in VB6, though, is very different because of a fundamental difference in the event models between COM and .NET.

I won't go into how VB6 implemented the feature; that isn't really relevant. What's important is how events work with .NET. Basically, with .NET, events have to be explicitly hooked and unhooked. When events are defined, there are a lot of parallels with how properties are defined. In particular, there is a method that adds a handler to an event and a method that removes a handler, similar to the symmetry between the "set" and "get" methods a property has.

The reason events use methods like this is to hide the list of attached handlers from outside callers. If code outside of a class had access to the full list of attached handlers, it would be possible for it to interfere with it, which would be a very poor programming practice potentially resulting in very confusing behaviour.

VB.NET exposes direct calls to these event "add" and "remove" methods through the `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` operators. In C#, exactly the same underlying operation is expressed using the `+=` and `-=` operators, where the left-hand argument is an event member reference.

What `WithEvents` gives you is syntactic sugar that hides the `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` calls. What's important to recognize is that the calls *are still there*, they're just implicit.

So, when you write code like this:

```
Private WithEvents _obj As ClassWithEvents

Private Sub _obj_GronkulatedEvent() Handles _obj.GronkulatedEvent
  ...
End Sub
```

..you are asking VB.NET to ensure that *whatever object is assigned to `_obj`* (keeping in mind that you can change that object reference at any time), the event `GronkulatedEvent` should be handled by that `Sub`. If you change the reference, then the old object's `GronkulatedEvent` should be immediately detached, and the new object's `GronkulatedEvent` attached.

VB.NET implements this by turning your field into a property. Adding `WithEvents` means that the field `_obj` (or, in your case, `_item`) is *not actually a field*. A secret backing field is created, and then `_item` becomes a property whose implementation looks like this:

```
Private __item As ItemViewModel ' Notice this, the actual field, has two underscores

Private Property _item As ItemViewModel
  <CompilerGenerated>
  Get
    Return __item
  End Get
  <CompilerGenerated, MethodImpl(Synchronized)>
  Set(value As ItemViewModel)
    Dim previousValue As ItemViewModel = __item

    If previousValue IsNot Nothing Then
      RemoveHandler previousValue.GronkulatedEvent, AddressOf _item_GronkulatedEvent
    End If

    __item = value

    If value IsNot Nothing Then
      AddHandler value.GronkulatedEvent, AddressOf _item_GronkulatedEvent
    End If
  End Set
End Property
```

So, why does this cause the "lag" you see? Well, you can't pass a property "ByRef". To pass something "ByRef", you need to know its memory address, but a property hides the memory address behind "get" and "set" methods. In a language like C#, you would simply get a compile-time error: A property is not an L-value, so you cannot pass a reference to it. However, VB.NET is more forgiving and writes extra code behind the scenes to make things work for you.

In your code, you are passing what *looks like* a field, the `_item` member, into `SetProperty`, which takes the parameter `ByRef` so it can write a new value. But, due to `WithEvents`, the `_item` member is really a property. So, what does VB.NET do? It creates a temporary local variable for the call to `SetProperty`, and then assigns it back to the property after the call:

```
Public Property Item As ItemViewModel
  Get
    Return _item ' This is actually a property returning another property -- two levels of properties wrapping the actual underlying field -- but VB.NET hides this from you
  End Get
  Set
    ' You wrote: SetProperty(_item, value)
    ' But the actual code emitted by the compiler is:
    Dim temporaryLocal As ItemViewModel = _item ' Read from the property -- a call to its Get method

    SetProperty(temporaryLocal, value) ' SetProperty gets the memory address of the local, so when it makes the assignment, it is actually writing to this local variable, not to the underlying property

    _item = temporaryLocal ' Once SetProperty returns, this extra "glue" code passes the value back off to the property, calling its Set method
  End Set
End Property
```

So, because `WithEvents` converted your field to a property, VB.NET had to defer the actual assignment to the property until after the call to `SetProperty` returns.

Hope that makes sense! :-)

Comment: Follow up: There are legacy issues making the use of IDisposable prohibitively difficult. Since we can't implement IDisposable and rely on Dispose() being called to clean up the remaining handles the thought was that using WithEvents would work around this and handle the clean up for us.
**1)** Does WithEvents actually release the handles when the object is no longer used so it gets properly garbage collected?
**2)** Is there an alternative to IDisposable that would allow us to use AddHandler and RemoveHandler without leaking handles when the object is no longer needed?

Comment: Hmm, well, no, `WithEvents` doesn't do anything at all with regard to disposing objects, because it doesn't have any connection to object lifetime. There really is only one way to make sure that objects that need to be disposed actually get disposed, and that is to call the `Dispose` method. If you are using the object during a specific scope of code, you can arrange for this to take place automatically with a `Using` statement.

Comment: With regard to event handlers and memory leaks, the situation where a leak can occur is when you have a short-term object that hooks an event, and then you are finished with the object but you do not unhook the event. That process of hooking the event makes a reference from the source of the event back to the object -- after all, it has to be able to call an event handler method in the object -- so the garbage collector thinks the object is still alive. There are two solutions to this:

Comment: Firstly, the correct architecture is to make the short-term object implement `IDisposable`, and have it unhook the event when it is disposed. Then, make sure that the consumer of the object calls `Dispose` when it no longer needs the object.

Comment: Secondly, if you are writing the event source, it is possible, though a tad complicated, to use the `WeakReference` class to refer to the object instance. Doing so requires things like peeking into the delegate's invocation list in the `Add` and `Remove` handlers, and also verifying that the object is still there when dispatching the event back to the handlers. But it is an approach that is used on occasion to ensure that having hooked the event does not keep an object alive.